# Reduced Precision Numeric Data

Tags: r

I need to be able to efficiently retrieve R data across a network. The typical dataset I'm trying to retrieve consists of a few hundred thousand numbers.

I'm currently using saveRDS to store the data and readRDS to retrieve it, which is giving me decent performance. But some of the pre-computed results can still end up in the dozens of MB range due to the fact that R's storing each number in 4 bytes. For my application, I don't need any more accuracy than a 1 or, at most, 2 byte integer, so I'm thinking I could save some time by storing the binary data in another format.

I haven't been able to find anything online about efficiently storing R data in reduced precision formats. Obviously, I could read and write to/from my own binary format, but I envision that the overhead of the loop doing that in R would far outweigh any performance benefits I'd get by reducing the read/transfer time over the network.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started writing a package, [pack](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pack) to help with a problem like this.  I was using it to support another package that was an API to a [now-defunct service](http://blog.fosstrading.com/2009/04/opentick-is-no-more.html).

If you just want a 1-byte integer (<256) you can use `as.raw` and send the result; then use `as.integer` on the machine receiving the data.

```
> as.raw(255)
[1] ff
> as.integer(as.raw(255))
[1] 255
```

For a 2-byte integer, you can use `pack` and send the result; then use `unpack` on the machine receiving the data.

```
> library(pack)
> pack("v", 255)
[1] ff 00
> pack("v", 256)
[1] 00 01
> unpack("v", as.raw(255))
[[1]]
[1] 255
```

I've never used it, but I've heard good things about [RProtoBuf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RProtoBuf/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! `as.raw` wasn't quite enough accuracy for me, but the `short` int in your package may do just the trick!